# MongoDB Document Migrations

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We currently version our document "schemas" using a `__schemaVersion` stored against a given document e.g:

```js
db.collection.insertOne({
  _id: "123",
  __schemaVersion: 1,
  name: "Lewis Hamilton"
}
```

This allows our application code to decide how to handle a document based on `__schemaVersion` so, for example, if we were to change the schema like this:

```js
db.collection.insertOne({
  _id: "234",
  __schemaVersion: 2,
  firstName: "Lewis",
  lastName: "Hamilton"
});
```

We have a few options such as ignoring specific schema versions:

```js
const user = db.collection.findOne({ _id: "123", __schemaVersion: { $gte: 2 } });
```

Or handle both document schemas in code:

```js
const user = db.collection.findOne({ _id: "123" });
switch(user.__schemaVersion) {
  case 1:
     const nameParts = user.name.split(' ');
     return {
        ...user,
        name: undefined,
        firstName: nameParts[0],
        lastName: nameParts[1],
     }
  default:
    return user;
}
```

These approaches work fine, however there are times where we don't want to support multiple document schema versions as it can make our application code complicated.

I'd therefore like to perform ad hoc document migrations as and when they come into our application. e.g.

```js
const user = db.collection.findOne({ _id: "123" });
switch(user.__schemaVersion) {
  case 1:
    const nameParts = user.name.split(' ');
    return db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: "123", __schemaVersion: 1 }, { $set: { __schemaVersion: 2, firstName: nameParts[0], lastName: nameParts[1] }, $unset: { name: false } }, { returnOriginal: false });
  default:
    return user;
}
```

However, I'm using [`node-mongodb-native`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) and cannot find a hook to ensure that all documents which come into our application are migrated, i.e. I need to be able to hook into every mongodb driver method which possibly returns a document, e.g. `find`, `findOne`, `findOneAndDelete`, `findOneAndReplace`, `findOneAndUpdate` and probably many others? -- this would ensure my application has some form of guarantee that it's only working with migrated documents.

Does anybody know if `node-mongodb-native` offers a hook into the driver which handles this -- or of a wrapper which offers this functionality (ideally not Mongoose, but I would still be interested to hear whether Mongoose supports document migrations).

Additionally it'd be great if it supported a traditional ORM-style migration API where it'd migrate from 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 so migration scripts just have to know how to migrate from one version to the next, e.g. 2 -> 3, not 2 -> 4.